# Usage of Fine Code Coverage in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2022, vs-community-edition

I've installed the extension Fine Code Coverage (Version 1.1.191) in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. I got a few xUnit test-projects in my solution. I'm getting the coverage statistics and the report by using the following settings:

1. run the tests from the visual studio Test Explorer (not the xunit testrunner)
2. Test => Options => Fine Code Coverage => RunMsCodeCoverage:

   - selection of "No" or "IfInRunSettings" produces the mentioned output
   - selection of "Yes" and not providing runsettings fails to produce any output and the Output window for FCC gives the message "No cobertura files for ms code coverage"

The [README](https://github.com/FortuneN/FineCodeCoverage#readme) of the project states for the usage of MS Code Coverage with FCC:

> Firstly you need to change the RunMsCodeCoverage option from No.
> Ms code coverage requires a runsettings file that is configured appropriately for code coverage. This requires that you have the ms code coverage package and have pointed to it with the TestAdaptersPaths element as well as specifying the ms data collector.

...

> FCC does not require you to do this. If you do not provide a runsettings and RunMsCodeCoverage is Yes then FCC will generate one. If RunMsCodeCoverage is IfInRunSettings then if the project has runsettings that includes the ms data collector element configured correctly then FCC will process the collected results.

As pointed out in my settings above I do not get a result if "RunMsCodeCoverage" is set to "Yes" without providing runsettings. On the other hand setting "IfInRunSettings" without providing runsettings I'm getting the desired output (are the runsettings generated automatically in this case?). So I find the description in the README in contrast to my results. Could it be that the documentation in this point is referring to the enterprise edition of VS? I'd like to be able to understand the different setup options/requirements so anyone who can shed a light on these is welcome.